# Where to show final solution to a question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I finally found a solution to my problem. It is mainly based on an other user's answer but it needs some rearrangement to fit to my specific needs. I think about displaying the final code for any potentially interested users but where to put it ?

- Editing the question to put it at the end does not feel right. We don't want the answers to be in the question. Do we ?
- Adding an answer is a bit off since the upvotes we could get should be for the OP
- We could add the final code in a comment on the accepted answer but there will be no code formatting.

So what is the best way to do this? Or could we expect a new dedicated place for the finally used solution.

Answer (score 4):

I would edit the question. I see no harm in having the answer in the question, really. Indeed, in the past I've seen questions where the questioner has edited them with an "eventual solution" section which talked about multiple original answers being involved.

So clarify what you actually had to do in the question, but accept the answer which provided you the most benefit towards reaching the solution.

Comment: To be safe, if you have an accepted solution, it might be good to comment in that section that you added a full solution to the question itself, in case people scroll down to find the answer.

Comment: You will NEVER need to scroll down to see an answer on this site.

Comment: @Downvoter It is a good thing to scroll down on old questions because someone may have added an up to date answer which will have low votes.

Answer (score 2):

I usually add the final code directly to the most useful answer body, mark it as correct, and leave a comment to notify the original author, so he can fix it if he cares.

Comment: I agree with this solution but it is limited to users who can edit answers.

Comment: Well, since _everyone_ can now suggest edits, this would be the way to go.